# true three index tensors

Tags: tensor-calculus

is such a *tensor*, $T_{\alpha\beta\, \gamma}$, possible such that
$$T_{\alpha\beta\, \gamma}=T_{\beta\alpha\, \gamma}=-T_{\alpha\gamma\, \beta}=-T_{\gamma\beta\, \alpha}$$
That is, symmetric under two indices, but antisymmetric under the third with the previous too.  If so can it be build up by a linear combination and "multiplication" of 4-vectors?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly your tensor would have to obey, 
$$T_{abc} = -T_{cba} = -T_{bca} = T_{acb} =  -T_{abc},$$
and therefore would have to be equal to zero.